# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc application:-

```
 @model MvcApplication4.Models.ContactsDetails
     <h3>Select Contacts Detials</h3>
    <p class="dashboarder" style = "color:#5c87b2"><strong>@Model.Info.Count()</strong> Selected Customers Accounts.</p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", null))
    {
        Int32 c = -1;
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Account Name @Html.CheckBox("IncludeAccountName", true)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name @Html.CheckBox("IncludeName", true)
                </th>
```

which is populated using the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult CustomersDetails(long[] SelectRight)
{

    if (SelectRight == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("customer", new { isError = true });
    }
    else
    {

        var ContactsDetails2 = new ContactsDetails
        {
            Info = r.getcontactinfo(SelectRight)
        };
        return View(ContactsDetails2);

    }          


}
```

and then the following repository method:-

```
public IEnumerable<AaaUserContactInfo> getcontactinfo(long[] id)
{
    var organizationNames = entities.SDOrganizations
                   .Where(org => id.Contains(org.ORG_ID))
                   .Select(org => org.NAME);


    var result = from userContactInfo in entities.AaaUserContactInfoes
                 join contactInfo in entities.AaaContactInfoes on userContactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID equals contactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID
                 where organizationNames.Contains(contactInfo.EMAILID.ToString())
                 select userContactInfo;
    return result;
```

but when i run mu application i got th folloiwng unclear error on the view :-

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

on the following code:-

```
<strong>@Model.Info.Count()</strong>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx) method instead of `ToString` (which cannot be converted into SQL):

```
where organizationNames.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(contactInfo.EMAILID))
```

If `EMAILID` is not double or decimal, then just cast value to one of those types.